# Unwanted calls when hovering between elements inside <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write JS code.
The purpose is that when I hover the mouse over the div bloc, a script will be called to one of the elements.
I have a problem, because when I'm moving the cursor between elements in that div, the div is calling multiple "mouseover" events.

I wrote this sample code
The code adds a character to H1 every time I hover the div bloc.
But also, it adds character when I move the cursor from ex. H1 to H2

The script should only be called once when I hover over the div, not when I'm moving the cursor trough elements in that div.

```js
// Get references to HTML elements
var divElement = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var h1Element = divElement.querySelector("h1");
var addedCharacter = false;

// Add an event listener for hovering over the <div>
divElement.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  if (!addedCharacter) {
    // Add the "1" character permanently only to the H1 header
    h1Element.textContent += "1";
    addedCharacter = true;
  }
});

// Add an event listener for leaving the <div> with the cursor
divElement.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  addedCharacter = false;
});
```

```css
/* Add some style to the div and headers */

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <h1>Text 1</h1>
  <h2>Text 2</h2>
  <h3>Text 3</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`. See the linked question for an explanation.

Comment: So simple solution, only one word :)
Thanks a lot. I was struggling with this problem for over 2h.